# Managing spring beans creation and dictionary

Tags: spring, spring-bean

I've to manage the association between bean instance and some type of resource. More specifically, when I receive some data associated to Resource A, I have to dispatch the data to the create an instance of some bean type every time I receive data associated with a specified resource. For example, if I receive some data associated with Resource "a", then i have to dispatch this data to a Bean instance associated with "a". If there isn't a Bean instance associated to Resource "a", then it has to be created. The number of Resource isn't statically known, and it will be known only during execution.

I understand I need some type of dictionary to store the association between Resource id and bean instance, building something like a Factory to manage bean creation.
How can I implement this in Spring? What's the proper way?

Comment: If the number of keys is infinite you cache will rather be a memory leak, if the number is constant then you can forsee the number of objects and create the beans before. If there's a (hash like) function that projects the keys to some smaller finite set of keys  may be it will work but anyway caching by creating separate beans seems strange to me. IMHO you should move caching to some lower level abstraction and use spring caching capabilities instead of creating beans. Ie cache some DTOs or entities returned by the services.

Comment: The number of beans will be, of course, finite, and it will be even less of the number of user interacting with the application (using a per-session scoped bean will result in a larger number of beans).

Answer (score 0):

the Spring `ApplicationContext` can be referred to in this 'dictionary' fashion.  that is, you specify to the application context to 'setup' the 'resource beans'.  you then map the 'received data' via way of a `Map` object, that, in turn, holds a reference to the bean.  once the data maps to the bean, you can then retrieve the bean and process the received data.  here's a brief example

here's a resource service interface

```
package de.incompleteco.spring.service;

public interface ResourceService {

    public void processData(Object data);

}
```

here's an implementation to process 'TypeA' data

```
package de.incompleteco.spring.service;

public class TypeAResourceService implements ResourceService {

    public void processData(Object data) {
        //do something for 'type A' data
    }

}
```

here's a 'delegate' service

```
package de.incompleteco.spring.service;

import java.util.Map;

import de.incompleteco.spring.domain.TypeA;
import de.incompleteco.spring.domain.TypeB;

public class DelegateResourceService implements ResourceService {

    private Map<String,ResourceService> services;

    public void processData(Object data) {
        if (data instanceof TypeA) {
            services.get(TypeA.class.getSimpleName()).processData(data);
        } else if (data instanceof TypeB) {
            services.get(TypeA.class.getSimpleName()).processData(data);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("...");
        }
    }

    public void setServices(Map<String, ResourceService> services) {
        this.services = services;
    }

}
```

the 'delegate' service is responsible for retrieving the right service from a map to process the right data (keyed by Class Name)

here's the spring configuration to support

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <!-- type 'a' bean -->
    <bean id="typeA" class="de.incompleteco.spring.service.TypeAResourceService"/>

    <!-- type 'b' bean -->
    <bean id="typeB" class="de.incompleteco.spring.service.TypeBResourceService"/>

    <util:map id="dictionary">
        <entry key="TypeA" value-ref="typeA"/>
        <entry key="TypeB" value-ref="typeB"/>
    </util:map>

    <bean class="de.incompleteco.spring.service.DelegateResourceService">
        <property name="services" ref="dictionary"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

this configuration does the following;

- sets up services for type A and B data
- maps those services to keys
- sets up the delegate service, setting the map to be used

this pattern is not the only way of doing it, but gives you the following;

- ability to configure the service beans independantly
- the delegate only needs a map to process
- the constraint is that the service objects have to be of the same interface

you can think of the Spring ApplicationContext as a giant factory, but (in many ways) a whole lot simpler to setup.

Comment: mmmmm thank you for your suggestion but there is a problem: I don't know statically what will be the resources I will receive. Instead of thinking to the resource in a typed manner (`TypeA`, `TypeB`), think it in a dynamic value-based manner (`resource.getValue()=="a"`, `resource.getValue()=="b"`, where possible values are not known). In this way I can't specify the map values in the configuration file, but I need something like `if(!map.contains(resource.getValue()) createDelegate(resource);`.